# UICollection View Adjust Cell Size for Screen Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently i have a collection view which takes up most of my screen at the 3.5 inch screen size.The collection view is 51 pixels from the top and 20 pixels from the bottom of the screen.  I am using the cells with `UIPageControl` to create a paged layout, with one cell per page. When switching to the 4 inch size, using constraints i can get the collection view to expand into the new space (maintaining the 51 pixels from the top and 20 from bottom), but the cell size stays the same, so now there is a bunch of empty space at the top and bottom of the cell. I tried using constraints, but it appears you can't set them for cells. How do i expand the cell size bigger to fill the empty space on the iPhone 5?

The collection view code is just

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;

}
```

The layout is setup in IB I want to get the layout working first before I add more

[image: iPhone 5 view. I want to fill the empty space]

[image: iPhone 4 view]

Comment: can you plz put code snippet that you have used?

Comment: @iSwap its nothing much I just made a basic collection view, with the layout setup in interface builder. The collection view works fine, I just need to figure out how to make the cell take up the empty space on the iphone 5

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can either use the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` method `itemSize` property to set the `UICollectionViewCell` size, or use the `delegate` method, `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` if you need to dynamically set the sizes of the `UICollectionViewCells`.

Comment: @rdelmar What are the pros and cons of the two methods you stated?

Comment: @Sanne, itemSize is sets the default size for the cells, and is fine if you want all cells to be the same size. Use the delegate method if you need to return different sizes for items at particular index paths.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> CollectionView layout Delegate that will help you to resize your Cell as you need.
> ```

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                          layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout 
          sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: wouldn't be bad to tell whats the deal with your code!

Comment: The poster asked: *"How do i expand the cell size bigger to fill the empty space"*. He/she did *not* ask for a function name. If you are going to provide a one line function name without explaining how to use it, you should probably add it as a comment to the original question.

Comment: this is a simple delegate, what else explaination is required ? and Question :: UICollection View Adjust Cell Size for Screen Size. so i think this answer have enough clarification ? 亚历山大 you tell me how would i explain it more ?

Comment: same explaination as you use HeightForRow Delegate and return CGFloat for the required Height, in this scenrio you will return the CGSize that you want for your CollectionViewCell .. Clear ? tell me if you face any issue :)

Comment: Hey posters before, RTFM does not help anymore?

Comment: @Andy if you're facing any issue you can ask with me.