# Resize UICollectionViewCell for different devices with AutoLayout and iOS 8

Tags: ios8, autolayout

I am new to iOS programming so please bear with my ignorance. Now, I am building an app similar to the "Photos" app from iOS using CollectView. So, there is a imageView inside the CollectionViewCell. I have set constraints on the imageView and the Cell so when the cell is resized, the imageView is also resized. I have built it based on the dimension of the iPad simulator and it works fine. Now, my problem is porting my app to iPhones - the cell and images remain the same size as in the iPad. What I want to do is they should scaled down accordingly with the dimension of the device (the same image should appear smaller in iPhones). I have tried detecting the device and setting the itemsize  (all the images are of the same dimension so I am not using sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) of the collectionViewFlowLayout programmatically but it means I have to calculate and hardcode the width and height of the cell for different devices. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution with the coming of iOS8 and AutoLayout without resorting to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using size classes. [Here](http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/) you have a great tutorial to learn how to use.

Comment: I have tried that. The problem I encountered is that the image is resized but the cell is not. So, when I switch to iPhone, the image is sized correctly because of the constraints but there are very big gaps/padding because the cell is the same size as when it was in the iPad. It does not seem to be possible to add constraints on CollectionViewCell. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can do by code. If is iPad you resize the cell. Look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272216/uicollection-view-adjust-cell-size-for-screen-size

Comment: I know I can do by code but I am trying to avoid that. Instead I am wondering if iOS 8 offer a more elegant solution with the use of size classes/adaptive layout. I thought I mentioned this in my question already. I have tried size classes already but problem is you can only set constraints on the ImageView to the Cell, so that ImageView does resize but not the Collection View Cell. And I cannot find any way to make the Cell Resize by using size classes.